# Hibernate Envers: Problem querying revisions

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I use Hibernate Envers for auditing. My entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class Child
{
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String test;

    // getters & setters
}
```

Now I would like to query revisions like this:

```
query = reader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(Child.class, false, true);
query.add(AuditEntity.property("test").eq("child1"));

Long id = ...;
query = reader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(Child.class, false, true);
query.add(AuditEntity.property("id").eq(id));
```

The first query works, executing the second throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.util.Map
    at org.hibernate.property.MapAccessor$MapGetter.get(MapAccessor.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.getPropertyValue(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.getPropertyValues(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getPropertyValues(ComponentType.java:381)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeGetValues(ComponentType.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeSet(ComponentType.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:567)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1612)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:717)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2294)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2172)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2167)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:448)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1258)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.envers.query.impl.AbstractAuditQuery.buildAndExecuteQuery(AbstractAuditQuery.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.envers.query.impl.RevisionsOfEntityQuery.list(RevisionsOfEntityQuery.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.envers.query.impl.AbstractAuditQuery.getResultList(AbstractAuditQuery.java:101)
```

I have no clue why this leads to a ClassCastException. Any idea, what I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When comparing the ids of two audited entities, use `AuditEntity.id()` instead of `AuditEntity.property()`.

Answer (score 5):

the id of an entry of a _aud table is made of the id of the entity, the REV, and the REVTYPE, so, its a map of 3 values. the best choice is using AuditEntity.id(), but AuditEntity.property("id.id") would also make it